# Issue with ModelState (is invalid) when setting up relationships and trying to create a create form in C# / ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, web-applications, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem the following problem: when I am in "Create" Movies form after providing all necessary details and pressing "Create" button nothing happens. It says that my model state is not valid when it comes to choosing foreign keys:

```
Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable   

[0] {[Name, SubKey={Name}, Key=Name, ValidationState=Valid]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[1] {[Price, SubKey={Price}, Key=Price, ValidationState=Valid]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[2] {[Cinema, SubKey={Cinema}, Key=Cinema, ValidationState=Invalid]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[3] {[EndDate, SubKey={EndDate}, Key=EndDate, ValidationState=Valid]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[4] {[CinemaId, SubKey={CinemaId}, Key=CinemaId, ValidationState=Valid]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[5] {[ImageURL, SubKey={ImageURL}, Key=ImageURL, ValidationState=Valid]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[6] {[Producer, SubKey={Producer}, Key=Producer, ValidationState=Invalid]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[7] {[StartDate, SubKey={StartDate}, Key=StartDate, ValidationState=Valid]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[8] {[ProducerId, SubKey={ProducerId}, Key=ProducerId, ValidationState=Valid]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
[9] {[Description, SubKey={Description}, Key=Description, ValidationState=Valid]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry>
```

I am unsure why this is happening. Please help.

This is my movies controller:

```
    // GET: Movies/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["CinemaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Cinemas, "Id", "Description");
        ViewData["ProducerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Producers, "Id", "Bio");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Movies/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,Price,ImageURL,StartDate,EndDate,CinemaId,ProducerId")] Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["CinemaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Cinemas, "Id", "Description", movie.CinemaId);
        ViewData["ProducerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Producers, "Id", "Bio", movie.ProducerId);

        return View(movie);
    }
```

This is my movies model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        /*public MovieCategory MovieCategory { get; set; }*/

        //Relationships
        /*public List<Actor_Movie> Actors_Movies { get; set; }*/

        //Cinema
        public int CinemaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CinemaId")]
        public Cinema Cinema { get; set; }

        //Producer
        public int ProducerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProducerId")]
        public Producer Producer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want the data to be saved into my database. Unfortunately nothing happens when I press "create" button.

Comment: You have a two port application.  Port 1 is the front end which is a http connection from a client to servers.  The server is implemented using a controller.  Port 2 is the back end where you are using Entity (dbContext) to connect to a database.  Entity contains a mapping between the c# class model and the table/fields in the database.  When the model changes (not when data changes), you need to use Migration to update the database to match the model.  Migration has two modes Create and Update.  I suspect you need to use Update and Not Create when you run Migration.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your response. Unfortunately I do not understand much from it, what do you mean I should update not create? Create form works everytime unless I specify a relationship. Then it stops working. It does not make any sense

Comment: Your error is due to the Model (c# class) not matching the Database Tables/Fields.  Create in this case is not creating the form.  Create is a term in Migration for creating a database from the c# classes.

Answer (score 0):

> It says that my model state is not valid when it comes to choosing
> foreign keys:

From you model state , we can see your `Cinema`  and `Producer` filed is invalid, so your  model state is not valid.  Try to set a breakpoint at post  `Create(Movie movie)` to see the value of `Movie movie`, you will  find the  `Cinema` and `Producer` property are null, because we don't input Cinema and Producer.

Try to add a `?` to your property like:

```
 public Cinema? Cinema { get; set; }
 public Producer? Producer { get; set; }
```

Comment: this did not help unfortunately

Comment: @md317 ,  after change the model class,  do you update the migration and database ? Threre is another way to avoid this null error,  you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file
(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

Comment: Inserting "?" actually worked...my bad. Thanks man.